# Ajax doesn't change my $_SESSION variable

Tags: php, ajax, session, session-variables

I have main.php page with a `$_SESSION` variable, i call ajax to modify this var, on the ajax the `$_SESSION` var changes but when I check it on my main.php it didn't.

I have `session_start();` on each and the ID on `session_id();` is the same.

If reload the page the values are modified

main.php

```
<?php session_start();echo session_id();$_SESSION['equipo_g']=0 ?>
...
<!--SCRIPT CALLED BY BUTTON-->
<script>
function pdf(){ 

if (window.XMLHttpRequest){
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else{
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function(){
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
    document.getElementById("pdf").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  } 

var e = document.getElementById("equipos_g");
var equipo = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

xmlhttp.open("GET","test.php?r="+equipo,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
...
<!--Trigger a func to call the ajax-->
<button type="button" onclick="pdf();">Preparar Grafica</button>
...
<div id"pdf"></div>
...
```

test.php

```
<?php 
session_start();
$r=$_GET["r"];

$_SESSION['equipo_g']=$r;
echo $_SESSION['estacion_g'];//The change is done

//Run a script that use $_SESSION['equipo_g']
echo '<button type="button" onClick="mostrar_graf1();" id="bot_grafica">Graficar</button>';
exit();
?>
```

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: Check it. I'll be here all night XD

Answer (score 0):

Try sending your session id along with your request:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","test.php?r="+equipo+"&sid=<?php echo session_id(); ?>",true);
```

and use it to set the session id prior to starting the session:

```
session_id($_GET['sid']);
session_start();
```

Also please note that if you call

```
$_SESSION['equipo_g']=0
```

on every load of main.php, you are setting your session variable `equipo_g` to zero before you try reading it.

Comment: For some reason the script doesn't work if i add that sentence:
xmlhttp.open("GET","test.php?r="+equipo+"&sid="+<?php echo session_id(); ?>,true);

Btw i delete $_SESSION['equipo_g']=0 from main.php

Comment: Horrible mistake on my side. I corrected it. Try again with the updated code from the answer.

Comment: Not working but the ID's are the same, check this: I clean my cookies this time on every run, then onClick="mostrar_graf1(); en the button id="bot_grafica doesn't work, the function just dont run, but If reload the page and try again it work.

Comment: LAST RESEARCH: I click on the button id="bot grafica" (with cookies cleaned and nothing happend) later i refresh the page and between that moment and the new page load's the script RUN! What can i do?

Answer (score 0):

At the end y just send all the values i need to the ajax and did the operations in php there, then send results like parameters to a JScript function using JSon! 
I dont wanna use it but well it works now thanks SquareCat :3
(here is the code):

test.php

```
<?php
$estacion=$_GET["estacion"];
$equipo=$_GET["equipo"];
$year=$_GET["year"];
$month=$_GET["month"];
$week=$_GET["week"];

$alldata=array();

//SOME MYSQL OPERATIONS USING THE VAR's PRODUCING $result_data

array_push($alldata,$result_data);
?>

<button type="button" onClick='mostrar_graf2(<?php echo  json_encode($alldata) ?>);' id="bot_grafica">Graficar</button>
```